SSH issue on vscode
I work in a company and I have a laptop that runs Windows. I'm used to using Vscode and connecting to a server using ssh. Until this morning, everything was working fine. I work on two servers dl0 and dl6. And since this morning I can no longer ssh dl6 remotely on VScode. If I use PowerShell I can connect to the server, otherwise not.
I don't understand. My configuration has not changed.
Something is weird : until now Vscode asked me my password just one time, and now, it can be 3, 4 or 5 times.
Here are my logs :

    16:58:41.144] Log Level: 2
    [16:58:41.163] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+frqsurmed1lxdl6", attempt 1
    [16:58:41.164] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
    [16:58:41.164] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
    [16:58:41.164] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"frqsurmed1lxdl0":"linux","frqsurmed1lxdl6":"linux"}
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
    [16:58:41.165] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
    [16:58:41.166] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
    [16:58:41.172] VS Code version: 1.95.0
    [16:58:41.172] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.115.0
    [16:58:41.172] win32 x64
    [16:58:41.175] SSH Resolver called for host: frqsurmed1lxdl6
    [16:58:41.175] Setting up SSH remote "frqsurmed1lxdl6"
    [16:58:41.187] Using commit id "912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95" and quality "stable" for server
    [16:58:41.190] Script variables:
     {
      "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
      "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
      "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
      "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
      "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
      "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
      "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
      "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
      "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
      "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
      "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
      "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
      "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
      "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
      "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
      "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
      "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
      "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
      "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
      "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
      "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
      "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
      "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
      "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
      "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
      "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
      "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
      "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
      "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
      "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
      "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
      "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
      "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
      "uuid": "55f552697cb6",
      "startMarker": "55f552697cb6: running",
      "commitId": "912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95",
      "quality": "stable",
      "token": "a1a11a11-aaa1-111a-a111-aa1a11aa1111",
      "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
      "allowClientDownload": "1",
      "forceClientDownload": "0",
      "cliNameInArchive": "code",
      "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
      "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
      "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
      "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
      "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "55f552697cb6:trigger_server_download",
      "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "55f552697cb6:trigger_server_download_end",
      "getProgressDownloading": "55f552697cb6%%1%%",
      "getProgressInstalling": "55f552697cb6%%2%%"
    }
    [16:58:41.193] Install and start server if needed
    [16:58:41.199] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\CCM\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.201] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\CCM\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.202] Checking ssh with "C:\Python311\Scripts\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.203] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python311\Scripts\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.203] Checking ssh with "C:\Python311\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.205] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python311\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.205] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\system32\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.206] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.207] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.209] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.209] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.210] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.211] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.212] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:41.212] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:41.271] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
    
    [16:58:41.275] Running script with connection command: "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 58725 frqsurmed1lxdl6 sh
    [16:58:41.277] Generated SSH command: 'type "C:\Users\320269~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-frqsurmed1lxdl6-610462104.sh" | "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 58725 frqsurmed1lxdl6 sh'
    [16:58:41.278] Using connect timeout of 17 seconds
    [16:58:41.279] Terminal shell path: C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
    [16:58:41.602] > ]0;C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
    [16:58:41.603] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
    [16:58:41.832] > CODE1\320269567@frqsurmed1lxdl6's password: 
    [16:58:41.833] Showing password prompt
    [16:58:52.677] Got password response
    [16:58:52.678] "install" wrote data to terminal: "****************"
    [16:58:52.706] > 
    [16:58:54.671] > 55f552697cb6: running
    > Script executing under PID: 3359114
    > Installing to /home/samba/320269567/.vscode-server...
    [16:58:54.689] > 55f552697cb6%%1%%       
    > Downloading with wget   
    > wget is from busybox: no
    [16:58:54.707] > Program 'wget' appears to support flag '--no-config'
    [16:58:54.717] > wget download failed
    > ERROR: cannot verify update.code.visualstudio.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=C
    > isco Umbrella Secondary SubCA cdg1-SG,O=Cisco’:
    >   Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
    > To connect to update.code.visualstudio.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certifica
    > te'.
    > printenv:
    >     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
    >     HTTPS_PROXY=http://146.112.255.50:443/
    >     no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,frqsurmed1lx001,.code1.emi.philips.com,.philips
    > .com,130.143.0.0/16
    >     USER=CODE1\320269567
    >     SSH_CLIENT=130.139.176.151 58726 22
    >     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
    >     SHLVL=0
    >     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/samba/320269567/miniforge3/lib:
    >     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
    >     HOME=/home/samba/320269567
    >     CONDA_SHLVL=1
    >     OLDPWD=/home/samba/320269567
    >     NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,frqsurmed1lx001,.code1.emi.philips.com,.philips
    > .com,130.143.0.0/16
    >     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/31369342/bus
    >     _CE_M=
    >     https_proxy=http://146.112.255.50:443/
    >     LOGNAME=CODE1\320269567
    >     http_proxy=http://146.112.255.50:80/
    >     _=/usr/bin/sh
    >     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
    >     XDG_SESSION_ID=11022
    >     _CE_CONDA=
    >     PATH=/home/samba/320269567/miniforge3/bin:/home/samba/320269567/miniforge3/c
    > ondabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
    > /usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    >     REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    >     ftp_proxy=http://146.112.255.50:80/
    >     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/31369342
    >     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    >     XML_CATALOG_FILES=file:///home/samba/320269567/miniforge3/etc/xml/catalog fi
    > le:///etc/xml/catalog
    >     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/samba/320269567/miniforge3/bin/python
    >     SHELL=/bin/bash
    >     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
    >     PWD=/home/samba/320269567/.vscode-server
    >     CONDA_EXE=/home/samba/320269567/miniforge3/bin/conda
    >     SSH_CONNECTION=130.139.176.151 58726 130.143.66.158 22
    >     FTP_PROXY=http://146.112.255.50:80/
    >     HTTP_PROXY=http://146.112.255.50:80/
    >     CONDA_PREFIX=/home/samba/320269567/miniforge3
    > Trigger local server download
    > 55f552697cb6:trigger_server_download
    > artifact==cli-alpine-x64==
    > destFolder==/home/samba/320269567/.vscode-server==
    > destFolder2==/vscode-cli-912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95.tar.gz==      
    > 55f552697cb6:trigger_server_download_end
    > Waiting for client to transfer server archive...
    > Waiting for /home/samba/320269567/.vscode-server/vscode-cli-912bb683695358a54ae0
    > c670461738984cbb5b95.tar.gz.done and vscode-server.tar.gz to exist
    [16:58:54.718] Got request to download on client for {"artifact":"cli-alpine-x64","destPath":"/home/samba/320269567/.vscode-server/vscode-cli-912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95.tar.gz"}
    [16:58:54.718] server download URL: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95/cli-alpine-x64/stable
    [16:58:54.718] Downloading VS Code server locally...
    [16:58:54.750] > 
    > 
    [16:58:55.417] Downloaded VS Code server to c:\Users\320269~1\AppData\Local\Temp\04c6c9b7-9a01-4f42-b44b-95a511489440
    [16:58:55.421] Renamed VS Code server to c:\Users\320269~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode_server_1730303935417\vscode-cli-912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95.tar.gz
    [16:58:55.421] Preparing to scp to host frqsurmed1lxdl6
    [16:58:55.424] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\CCM\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.426] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\CCM\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.426] Checking ssh with "C:\Python311\Scripts\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.427] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python311\Scripts\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.427] Checking ssh with "C:\Python311\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.428] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python311\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.428] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\system32\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.429] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.429] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.430] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.430] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.431] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.431] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.433] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
    [16:58:55.433] Checking ssh with "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
    [16:58:55.501] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
    
    [16:58:55.504] Expecting scp to be next to ssh at C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe
    [16:58:55.504] Testing scp with "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe"
    [16:58:55.587] scp exited with code: 1
    [16:58:55.587] Got stderr from scp: usage: scp [-346ABCOpqRrsTv] [-c cipher] [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config]
               [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option]
               [-P port] [-S program] [-X sftp_option] source ... target
    [16:58:55.588] Copying file to remote with "C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe" "vscode-cli-912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95.tar.gz" "vscode-cli-912bb683695358a54ae0c670461738984cbb5b95.tar.gz.done" frqsurmed1lxdl6:"/home/samba/320269567/.vscode-server"
    [16:58:55.588] Using cwd: file:///c%3A/Users/320269~1/AppData/Local/Temp/vscode_server_1730303935417
    [16:58:55.588] Terminal shell path: C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
    [16:58:55.903] > ]0;C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe
    [16:58:56.105] > CODE1\320269567@frqsurmed1lxdl6's password: 
    [16:58:56.105] Showing password prompt
    [16:59:04.840] Got password response
    [16:59:04.840] "Copy server to host" wrote data to terminal: "****************"
    [16:59:04.871] > 
    [16:59:05.613] > C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe: Connection closed
    [16:59:06.905] "Copy server to host" terminal command done

``


Thank's a lot for your help

